# Get the twitter profile image in my application in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

If I am signed in with twitter in my app not sign in with the new user, only sign in old user only.problem is Twitter profile image is not getting in my app.

if I am using in this line

```
let twitterimagedetail:NSString="\( FHSTwitterEngine.shared().getProfileImageURLString(forUsername: username as String, andSize: FHSTwitterEngineImageSizeOriginal))" as! NSString
self.splashapp.twitterimagecontent!=twitterimagedetail;
let url =  NSURL(string: "\(self.splashapp.twitterimagecontent!)")
```

error will be displayed as

> Optional(Error Domain=FHSErrorDomain Code=204 "The request did not
>   return any content

Answer (score 0):

Authorize the user with your twitter app and get the id of the user. Then use this url to get the image of the user from Twitter.

```
#define TWITTER_PROFILE_WITH_ID(id) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=%@",id]
```

Comment: Hi M.K This line displays the profile image in URL. how to get the profile image and email-id using JSON.

Comment: you needed only profile image right? you can save this url and you can display image from this url using any image cache in ios like SDWebImage. its working and tested. if you need other detail, then you should use fabric framework if there is any method to retrieve other user details. or you can use twitter api to get those details.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that info like this:

```
var web = "myTwitterAccount"

func consultarTweets(){
    self.consultarImagePerfil{ (result)->() in
        if let tweets = result as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let a:String = tweets["name"] as? String {
                print("Name: ",a)
            }
            if let a:String = tweets["screen_name"] as? String {
                print("ScreenName: ",a)
            }
            if let a:String = tweets["profile_image_url"] as? String {
                print("Profile Image ",a)
            }
        }
    }
 }

 func consultarImagePerfil(completion: (result: [String : AnyObject])->()) {
    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    let statusesShowEndpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"
    let params = ["screen_name" : "\(self.web)"]
    var clientError : NSError?
    let request = client.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: statusesShowEndpoint, parameters: params, error: &clientError)
    client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
        if connectionError != nil {
            print("Error: \(connectionError)")
        }
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
            print("json: \(json)")
            completion (result: json as! [String : AnyObject])
        } catch let jsonError as NSError {
            print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

And you can get more info here
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show